# Chrome Extension : Context menu on editable selected text only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

In Google Chrome Extension, I know how to show a context menu on selected text.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    'title': 'TEST',
    'contexts': ['selection'],
    'id': "test"
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    'title': 'submenu',
    'contexts': ['selection'],
    'id': "test_1",
    'parentId': "test",
    'onclick': menu.onClicked_
});
```

[image: context menu]

But I want to show this menu only if the selected text is in an "editable element" (input text, textarea, content editable DIV, ...). How can I do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried context `"editable"` instead of `"selection"`? The documentation is not very clear on what it would mean.

Comment: With `"editable"`, the menu appears only in editable element. But It appears even with no text selected.

Comment: Then I have doubts this is achievable.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like it's nearly impossible to achieve what you want.

[Chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#property-createProperties-contexts) defines 2 related contexts for context menus:

- `"editable"` context for all editable elements
- `"selection"` for selected fragments of a document

What you want is a logical AND between those, but Chrome only allows a logical OR.

Also consider that a selection can span more than an editable element. So you need a context that can be described as "text selection entirely within an editable element". Well, you can always [leave a feature request](https://crbug.com).

There may be hacky workarounds like trying to detect user selection with a content script on every page, and creating menus on the fly based on that, but I'm sure there are way, way too many corner cases for this.